# is there a way to print a list from alivepdf in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, alivepdf, spark-list

Does anybody know how can I print a list with alivepdf in actionscript?

I tried to adopt the logic of the spark grid (so to print the list as a grid) but it fails in printing the header of the printed grid.

I also wanted to print only its dataprovider but I'm not finding the right method to do  this.

Answer (score 0):

are you forced to use alivePdf in your project?
After lot of problems I used for creating pdf "purePdf" which is a porting of the iText java library.
It gives you more and more solutions than alivePdf and offers a good documentation.
You can get it from here: https://github.com/sephiroth74/purePDF

hope to have been helpful

Comment: I found a solution even with alivePDF. Thank you for your answer.